# Get multiple connections at once with Python facebook package

Tags: python, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

To get connections using the Python facebook package I know to use:

```
g.get_connections("me", "friends")
```

But is there a way to get "friends" and "books" in one call?

Didn't see anything in the docs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the Graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/), you can do a request in the form

```
GET graph.facebook.com
    /{node-id}?
        fields={first-level}
```

Thus, you'd want to execute a GET for `/me?fields=friends,books`, looking at the facebook-sdk code, the `g.get_object` seems to be the closest one, thus:

```
g.get_object('/me', fields='friends,books')
```

Of course chances are that not all are returned, and you need to page through the results anyway...